# is there a diy ice bath/pool that doesn't use a chest freezer / how do I keep small pool between 2°C and 16°C?

Tags: plumbing, refrigerator, pool, freezer

What could I use to cool water for a cold plunge pool that doesn't require a chest freezer. For example, I would form the pool area from concrete, line it with flex seal/rhino or some other waterproofing. What mechanical equipment do I need to efficiently cool the water?

I see pool chillers like: https://glacierpoolcoolers.com/ but I don't think they get cold enough and are for full size pools, not tubs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For some reason that glacier thing is trying to mislead customers to think that it's not an evaporative cooler, but their spare parts list spills the beans.  As such how cold it can get depends on how hot and humid the weather is.

Given that heat pumps (and the associated freon or butane plumbing) are not really a DIY thing, if you're wanting to do this yourself you'll probably need to go with a pre-built heat-pump system like you find in a chest freezer.

You could try Peltier-effect cooler blocks, they're DIY friendly, but they're fragile and expensive probably too expensive for anything larger than a foot bath.

Comment: AFAIK Peltier coolers are also very inefficient.

Comment: like, extremely inefficient, which is why *literally nobody uses them* except for demonstrations and novelty gadgets.

Comment: @user253751 not quite true - they have uses for cooling CPUs and mini-fridges, for example - but they won't do much for a plunge pool.  OTOH you could heat an attached sauna with the waste heat.